# Custom ordering of duplicate targets is not necessarily honored on mobile apps

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app, duplicate-questions, ios-app

The order of duplicates is different between apps and web. [E.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326558/339911):

iOS

> [image: ios]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 12.2 (Build 16E227)

Android

> [image: android]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LM-G710
- OS Version: 8.0.0 (190492326deb8.FGN)

Web

> [image: web]

Comment: Most of the queries don't have an explicit order by clause so it is left to the database to come up with one. It would be interesting to learn if the same queries are run here and if so, why their are ordered differently.

Comment: @rene the order of duplicates can be modified by mods or by gold-tag-badge owners

Comment: It seems like the apps order them by question IDs, with lower ones first.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ as a gold badge holder I can modify the duplicates, not its order (unless you mean by removing and re-adding them.

Comment: @rene actually we can also edit the order by dragging each item, and it then save the new order.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I never used that. Pretty cool

Comment: @rene I know! I'm almost sure that after editing the order and saving, the apps will show it correctly, need to test it somehow.

Comment: @ShadowWizard only for mouse-compatible devices. Created an [FR/BUG](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326919/339911)

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna call this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Or possibly [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), depending on how you look at it.

We are not currently in a position to make any changes to the mobile apps, and in the grand scheme of things I don't think this difference in the ordering matters that much.

Comment: [tag:status-declined] is the more appropriate tag to use here. [tag:status-bydesign] implies "we thought this through and this is intentional"; the former properly implies "we acknowledge this issue report, but we're not going to fix it".