# No (convenient) way to change targets order for duplicate on touch screen devices

Tags: bug, status-declined, duplicate-questions, touch-screen, drag-and-drop

If you’re a mod or have a gold-tag-badge you can close questions as duplicates of others and modify the list of such targets by clicking “edit” link under the list of target questions.

On platforms with a mouse, you can drag-n-drop items to change their order, but there is no convenient way to do so on touch screen only devices. I’ve tried on an iPad with no results. One ugly way is to remove all targets, then add them in the desired order.

Could this behavior be fixed please for touch screen only devices somehow?

Comment: One issue with this is that touchscreens send in mouse input in nonstandard ways, e.g. the way iOS devices do it is not the same way that Windows devices do it, etc.

Comment: Is there any place on SE where drag and drop does work for mobile device? (Not for built in browser elements.)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. Our team has reviewed and opted not to pursue this.